# How to track/monitor socket connection in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, tomcat

We have a spring boot (with zuul) app using default embedded tomcat (I think). It has many clients implemented with different technologies and languages. And we have problem with too many port in TIME_WAIT: i.e. too many socket connections are opened/closed w.r.t the expected request behavior that should keep connections alive most of the time.

By retrieving the HttpRequest object in the deployed API, I can get information on the request header. This way I can track the http protocol used (http/1.1) and header parameter such as keep-alive (which, if present, is redundant with the use of http/1.1).

=> I would like to track opened and closed socket connections, but I don't see how?

Intermediate information would be better than nothing.

Note: I found some tutorial on a similar topic when using spring-websocket, but we don't.

Comment: At my knowledge, Tomcat doesn't provide an MBEAN that would answer to this problem, and anyway it the Operating System which is configured for a long or a short time spent in TIME_WAIT. Is it really necessary to have this information from inside of your application ? I see two workarounds : choose a smaller TIME_WAIT, make your application listen on 2 ports and put a load-balancer in front of it.

Comment: The application is it-self the load-balancer. The question is not about the length of the time wait, but to understand why the connection are not kept alive, while we setup it up to do so.

Comment: OK understood. As an intermediate information I suggest to add `%X` to your [Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes) pattern and this will indicate which requests lead to a keep-alive, and which lead to a close. You can track a user with  `%S` and correlate with `%X`. If a client just opens a socket without sending any request, you'll end with a TIME_WAIT without any log in the access log, this is like slowloris attack.